# AERMOD install error, using homebrew and gfortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, homebrew, gfortran

Hello I am trying to install the following

https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/courses/atsc507/ADM/aermod/

I have homebrew and been using for awhile. I have gfortran and when I type `gfortran --version` I receive the following information

```
~/Desktop/aermod_source $ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I am on step 3g typing in the following

```
gfortran -o aermod.x -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wall -frecursive -O3 modules.f aermod.f setup.f coset.f soset.f reset.f meset.f ouset.f inpsum.f metext.f iblval.f siggrid.f tempgrid.f windgrid.f calc1.f calc2.f prise.f prime.f sigmas.f pitarea.f output.f evset.f evcalc.f evoutput.f uninam.f -w
```

I run for about 45seconds then fails with the following output.

```
~/Desktop/aermod_source $ gfortran -o aermod.x -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wall -frecursive -O3 modules.f aermod.f setup.f coset.f soset.f reset.f meset.f ouset.f inpsum.f metext.f iblval.f siggrid.f tempgrid.f windgrid.f calc1.f calc2.f prise.f prime.f sigmas.f pitarea.f output.f evset.f evcalc.f evoutput.f uninam.f -w
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rlcalc_", referenced from:
      _calc_ in ccxXxd2H.o
      _evcalc_ in ccQiZHGX.o
```

I tried searching for the error message and have no luck, I notice that the version of gfortran that is being used in the instructions is  `GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0` I don't know if this would help but I was thinking of switching to that version.

Anyone have suggestions to would help unblock me?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all questions with Fortran. I do not see any reason for the C++ tag.

Comment: Did you try to look if that function or subroutine is present somewhere in the code? the normal instructions for the unresolved symbol errors apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix